# Relative importance with t-statistics in R

Tags: multivariate-analysis, caret, importance

I am currently running a multi-variate analysis in R. The regression looks as such :

```
lm1<- lm(NEP ~ Stand_Age + GPP + SPI_CRU+ N_Av + SPI_CRU:NHx + GPP:MAP + GPP:MAP_Trend + Clay_1km, data=df)
```

I am also computing the relative importance of the predictors based on t-statistics provided by the package `caret`.

```
library(caret)
VarImp(lm1)
```

This output of the variable importance analysis is:

```
 Overall
Stand_Age      1.618707
GPP           18.047711
SPI_CRU        6.934433
N_AvL          4.450045
N_AvM          2.908714
Clay_1km       3.064615
Stand_Age:GPP  1.976546
SPI_CRU:NHx    7.151114
GPP:MAP        3.884616
GPP:MAP_Trend  3.998731
```

First, I would like to know if it is statistically correct to aggregate variable (`N_AvL` and `N_AvM` are the same variable `N_Av`). This would mean that the importance of `N_Av`= `N_AvL` + `N_AvM`.
Second, I would like to know if it is correct to sum-up to 100% the variable importance estimates. For instance, `Stand_Age` importance estimate would be equal to:

```
Importance(Stand_Age)=[t-statistics(Stand_Age)/sum(all t-statistics values)]*100
```

Comment: What's importance here?

Comment: Importance is the value of the t-statistic

Comment: It's the same as picking variables based on p-values, which "statistically" a dubious procedure.

Comment: But it gives you an idea of its contribution in the model performance. If you remove a variable with high t-values, its impact on the model performance (R2 or MEF) will be higher than removing a variable with low t-statistics value. Anyway, this does not answer my questions.

Comment: Are you familiar with so called "stepwise regression"? Look at [this blurb](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/) on Stata web site for instance. What you're trying to do is similar to the idea of this thing. So, yes, my comment does answer your question but not in a way you expected. Then again, why would you need an answer that is expected?

Comment: So what are your suggestions then?